# determine when background service has completed

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-service

currently, i'm starting a background service using Intent in my app, but is there anyway of determining when the service has completed?

..possibly by using some kind of listener, or sending a message from the service, to the activity??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, activities and services can communicate: the easiest is to use a [custom broadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

Second, if your service is short lived and is outlived by activity invoking it, then you might instead consider using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to simply run your task in the background thread.

Answer (score 0):

The usual trick you can use here is create a `BroadcastReceiver` in the Activity that listens for a specific Intent and then when the Service stops itself fire off that Intent.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a broadcast `Intent` just before the service termination and implement a [broadcast receiver](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#Components).